# In argparse, is it possible to have source mutually exclusive args from multiple parent parsers?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

The following will setup a mutually exclusive group where only one of "-a" or "-b" is valid.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-a')
group.add_argument('-b')
```

I would like to instead provide the "-a" and "-b" args from other parsers. Something like:

```
a_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
a_parser.add_argument('-a')

b_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
b_parser.add_argument('-b')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.SOME_HOW_ADD_ARGS_FROM_OTHER_PARSER(a_parser)
group.SOME_HOW_ADD_ARGS_FROM_OTHER_PARSER(b_parser)
```

In both cases, I expect the following to throw an exception about using incompatible arguments:

```
parser.parse_args(['-a', '1', '-b', '1'])
```

The problem is I don't know if the 'SOME_HOW_ADD_ARGS_FROM_OTHER_PARSER` logic that I am missing exists. If it does exist, I don't know how to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Why are you creating multiple parsers?  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I want to create some sets of args that apply to certain subcommands. For some subcommands, it makes sense to have "-a" and "-b" where for others it only makes sense to have "-a". The "-a" and "-b" options should be mutually exclusive when available on the same subcommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way, but it uses some hidden attributes of the parser.  I'm using an idea developed for

> http://bugs.python.org/issue10984 `argparse add_mutually_exclusive_group should accept existing arguments to register conflicts`

Create the 2 parent parsers, with `add_help=False` (to prevent conflicts over the `-h` argument - this is standard parent parser procedure)

```
a_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
aaAction = a.parser.add_argument('-a')
b_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
bbAction = b_parser.add_argument('-b')

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[a_parser, b_parser])
group=parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
```

At this point `parser` has 3 actions (arguments), which can be seen in a 'private' attribute, `_actions`:

```
print parser._actions
""" 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-a'], dest='a', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-b'], dest='b', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
"""
```

The 1st is its own `help`, the others are inherited from the parents.  I also saved pointers to the these earlier, `aaAction` and `bbAction`.  Now we just need to add these to the `_group_actions` list of `group`:

```
group._group_actions.append(parser._actions[1]) # or (aaAction)
group._group_actions.append(parser._actions[2]) # or (bbAction)
```

If patch 10984 had been implement we could have written:

```
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(aaAction, bbAction)
```

which would have performed this append as part of creating the group.

We can test it with:

```
In [31]: print parser.format_help()
usage: ipython [-h] [-a A | -b B]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A
  -b B


In [32]: parser.parse_args(['-a','a'])
Out[32]: Namespace(a='a', b=None)

In [33]: parser.parse_args(['-a','a','-b','b'])
usage: ipython [-h] [-a A | -b B]
ipython: error: argument -b: not allowed with argument -a
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

This depends on several pieces of information:

- `add_argument` returns a pointer to the Action it just created.
- `parents` adds actions to the new parser by just copying Action points, i.e. by reference.
- knowing where a `parse` and `group` store their relevant lists of Actions.
- knowing how adding an action to group differs from adding it to a parser (not much).

I recommend testing code like this in an interactive shell (like `IPython`) where you can look at the attributes of `parser` and `group`.  And keep a copy of `Lib/argparse.py` handy. :)

patch 10984 has some added code to deal with the complication of having an action in more than one group.  Normally an action only belongs to one group.